# How do I create an N-Queens Problem with Genetic Algorithm child with constrained row and column?

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

For the N-Queen problem found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm to solve it.

However, let's say that I am trying to constrain the problem. We know that to get an attacking value of 0, you can't have queens in the same row and column. I limit the boards to always have a different row and column for each queen. I want the genetic algorithm to find a solution where the diagonals are also not attacking.

My problem is with creating a child for this solution using a genetic algorithm. What is a good way to generate a child from two parent boards that follows that the children must not have queens in overlapping rows and columns?

Comment: This question lacks focus on your environment. Please show what you have, e.g. the limiting of the board. If you only ask about creating childs, then show everything else needed.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding both overlapping rows and columns is difficult in a genetic algorithm. The typical approach is to implicitly represent the columns by the index in an array, and then have the queens represented by numbers 1..N.

So, a solution to the 8-queen problem would be represented by (5 1 8 4 2 7 3 6).

If you take any subset of the array you can mix it with another array and be guaranteed that there is one queen in each column (or row - however you prefer to think of this).

You can avoid both column and row overlap by using combinatorics (so there are N! arrangements instead of N^N), but the issue is that the representation required to do this (you can essentially use integers to represent full configurations) doesn't work as well for crossover operations. You will also run into the limit of integer representations. Using an array as above works fairly well, so I would suggest exploring that approach first.